# Access Ubuntu server from VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, moodle

I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS via VirtualBox. I followed the instructions from here to install Moodle with success.

How can I access moodle from another computer (on the same network)? I run `ifconfig -a` in the server and the server has IP address 10.0.2.15, but when I ping this IP from another pc (on the same network) says destination unreachable.

Can I access the server from another PC on the same network?

Comment: you must configure VirtualBox to allow this

Comment: Where is the instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP-address `10.0.2.15` seems to be an address from a virtual network interface. Set your Networkinterface to "Bridged" in the Virtual Box Settings for the VM. After that, you can set an IP-address of your physical Network in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Or use DHCP, if you have a DHCP Server.